# How to make custom QListWidgetItems in Pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to make custom QListWidgetItems in Pyqt5?

[image]

something like this but with images too and color personalization.

Comment: If the customization goes further than change of color or font you could condiser using a custom `QStyledItemDelegate` as the delegate of your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change color you can change the  stylesheet

Comment: but with images too